# Aggregate method not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Following is my Collection Called Run

```
var Run = [{
        ID: 1,
        Name: 'TestRun',
        Comments: 'TestRun',
        Status: [{
            Cur: 'Active',
            Mapper: {
                Area: 'BH',
                State: 'MH'
            }
        },
        {
            Cur: 'Inactive',
            Mapper: {
                Area: 'BO',
                State: 'DU'
            }
        }]
    }]
```

I would like to create a query when I get all the data with `'Area'` as `'BH'` so that I get the result as follows

```
    Status: [{
        Cur: 'Active',
        Mapper: {
             Area: 'BH',
             State: 'MH'
        }
   }]
```

When I fire this query in mongodb prompt:

```
db.Run.aggregate([ 
    {$match: {'Status.Mapper.Area': 'BO'}},
        {$project: { 
            Status: 
                {$filter: { 
                    input: '$Status', 
                    as: 'script', 
                    cond: {$eq: ['$$script.Mapper.Area','BO']}
            }},
        _id: 0
    }} 
]).pretty();
```

The result is as expected. However when I try to run this query using Nodejs it returns no result.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/exeexample';

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(error, db) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    db.collection('Run').find({ID: 1}).toArray(function(error, docs) {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
                process.exit(1);
            }

            console.log('found docs:1 ');
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
                db.collection('Run').aggregate([
                    {$match: {'Status.Mapper.Area': 'BO'}},
                    {$project: {
                        Status: {$filter: {
                            input: '$Status',
                            as: 'script',
                            cond: {$eq: ['$$script.Mapper.Area', 'BO']}
                        }},
                        _id: 0
                    }}
                ]).toArray(function(error, docs) {
                    console.log('found docs:2 ');
                docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                    console.log('found docs:3 ');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
                }); 
            }); 
            process.exit(0);
        });
    });
});
```

The query is almost same as the one I used in MongoDB prompt. Since no errors are thrown it seems there is something wrong with the filter clause. 
Appreciate your help with this.

Comment: It works fine when I try it. Make sure you're using the same DB in both cases.

Comment: Apologies, I thought only a snippet of the entire code would do to help solve my query. I have updated my question with the entire script. Please check

Comment: Are you also using the `exeexample` database when you try this in the shell (where it's working)?

Comment: Yes I am using exeexample exercise in the shell.

Comment: You're calling `process.exit(0);` before the async `aggregate` calls complete.

Comment: Oh yes, moved the statement inside the callback. Worked!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.exit(0);` was misplaced leading to this statement being executed before the async aggregate call completion. Thanks to [JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk)
Updated code is as follows:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/exeexample';

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(error, db) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    db.collection('Run').find({ID: 1}).toArray(function(error, docs) {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
                process.exit(1);
            }

            console.log('found docs:1 ');
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
                db.collection('Run').aggregate([
                    {$match: {'Status.Mapper.Area': 'BO'}},
                    {$project: {
                        Status: {$filter: {
                            input: '$Status',
                            as: 'script',
                            cond: {$eq: ['$$script.Mapper.Area', 'BO']}
                        }},
                        _id: 0
                    }}
                ]).toArray(function(error, docs) {
                    console.log('found docs:2 ');
                docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                    console.log('found docs:3 ');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
                }); 
             process.exit(0); **//Moved**
            });   
        });
    });
});
```